# Is it possible to use JS maps (Openlayers/Leaflet) in a slideshows (Views Slideshow/Flexslider)?

Tags: views, javascript

I have attempted to create a slideshow using [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) and [Flexslider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider) in Views, the content to be used includes a map displaying a track. The problem is that no map tiles or other layers are displayed, this is true for both Openlayers and Leaflet formatters.

As this content displays correctly using a List View but not a Slideshow View and it is a problem with two separate JS mapping libraries I am wondering if it has to do with how slideshows offset their content and then manipulate their positioning during operation that the mapping libraries can't deal with.

I am currently happy with the overhead using JS mapping in this instance instead of using a static image. Is it possible to use content of this type in a slideshow?